# Logical form of "All present Kings of France are bald."

Tags: logic

I'm reading Severin Schroeder's Wittgenstein right now. In the "Between Vienna and Cambridge" chapter he introduces Russell's and Whitehead's Logical Formalization: `x and y` is $x \supset y$ and `if x then y` is $x . y$ and so on.

Now in the "Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus" chapter Schroeder writes the following:

> (K1) There exists at least one present King of France.
>   (K2) There exists at the most one present King of France.
>   (K3) All present Kings of France are bald.
>
> In logical noation (Fx: x is a present King of France; Gx: x is bald):
>
> (K1') ($\exists$x)Fx
>   (K2') (x)(y)((Fx.Fy)$\supset$x=y)
>
> Read: Take anything x and anything y: if x is a present King of France
>   and y is a present King of France, then x and y are the same (person).
>   In other words, there aren't two different present kings of France.

The last paragraph puzzles me, for this really is not what I am reading there at all. Rather it'd be:

> Take anything x and anything y: if x is a present King of France **THEN** y is a present King of France, **AND** x and y are the same.

May someone please riddle me this?

Comment: Is the other way round : "x and y" will be symolized as $x.y$ while "if x, then y" with $x \supset y$.

Comment: I've browsed Schroeder's book on Google; page 18 : it is clearly a typo. If you see the example at page 19, the $\supset$ symbol has been used in the correct way, standing for "if ..., then ___".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula :

> (K2') $\quad \forall x \forall y ((Fx.Fy) \supset x = y)$

must be read as : take any $x$ and any $y$, if $x$ is a present King of France and $y$ is a present King of France, then $x$ and $y$ are the same thing. In other words, there aren't two different present kings of France.

The quantifier are in front of the sub-formula betwee parentheses: so their *scope* is all the sub-formula and the connective $\supset$ is inside the parentheses.

Your reading : take any $x$ and any $y$, if $x$ is a present King of France, then $y$ is a present King of France, and $x$ and $y$ are the same, correspond more exactly to :

> $\forall x \forall y (Fx \supset Fy).x = y))$

and the two are not the same.

The first formula is equivalent to :

> $\forall x \forall y (Fx \supset (Fy \supset x = y))$.

You can check with truth-tables (a contribution to mathematical logic mainly from Wittegenstein) that :

> $(p.q) \supset r$ and $p \supset (q \supset r)$

are *equivalent*, but they are *not* equivalent to :

> $(p \supset q).r$

Comment: You wrote: `Is the other way round : "x and y" will be symolized as x.y while "if x, then y" with x⊃y.` Do you stick to this in your answer?

Comment: @user3094719 - Yes, of course: they are the symbols used by Russell, and you can find them still used in some textbook.

Comment: So then one of the leading Wittgenstein scholars got this wrong? Please provide sources if you can.

Comment: @user3094719 - you are speaking of the symbolism ? If so, really your source has $x \supset y$ for "$x$ and $y$ ? You can check on Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, *Principia Mathematica to #56* (extract form 2nd ed - 1927). See page 6 : "The logical product is a propositional function with two arguments $p$ and $q$, and is the proposition asserting $p$ and $q$ conjunctively, that is, asserting that both $p$ and $q$ are true. This is denoted by $p.q$."; and see also page 7 : "The symbol employed for "p implies q" [...] is "$p \supset q$. This symbol may also be read "if p, then q"".